# Including .php pages after a form has been submitted

Tags: php, forms, include

I'm attempting to make a master-detail search page for my intranet that will allow me to search both staff and hardware from the same page. I've gotten part of the way there but I've gotten myself stuck and need some help.

I have the inventory page (index.php) setup and I've included a form with two button - "Staff" and "Hardware" - to include the master-details .php pages I've designed.

The code for this is as follows:

```
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Inventory</h1>
    <p></p>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="Staff" value="Staff" />
        <input type="submit" name="Hardware" value="Hardware" />
    </form>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['Staff']))
        {
            include 'details.php';
            include 'lib/staffsearch.php';
        };
        if (isset($_POST['Hardware']))
        {
            include 'detailhw.php';
            include 'lib/hwsearch';
        };
    ?>

  </div>
```

Again, this works fine - I click "staff" and it loads both my "staffsearch.php" and "details.php" pages. This is where I run into trouble however. My staffsearch.php includes a form that queries my staff database and returns the matching results in a table. I should be able to click on one of the results and the detailed information is displayed in the details box above. What happens though is that I click on the "Staff" button, my includes are displayed, I enter the search criteria, click "search" and get a blank page as a result.

If I click on the "staff" button again though my includes are reloaded along with the correct search result. Accessing the details however results in the same problem - once my results are displayed and I click on one instead of the details I receive a blank page until I click the "staff" button again - then my includes are reloaded and my results are displayed.

Is there anyway that when I click the search button on my staffsearch form that I can force the index page to reload the includes without having to click the "staff" button again?

Thanks, ahead of time for any advice as I'll throw in the mandatory. "I'm new to php" and my Googling hasn't really netted me any good results. If you need anymore information just ask!

**EDIT 1** 
The code for my searchstaff.php page is as follows:

```
<table width="598px" border="1" align="center">
  <tr valign="middle">
  <td alight="left" colspan="3">    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="">
    <label for="name">Search:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Submit" style="margin-left:10px";/>
</form>
</td>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" width="40px">No.</td>
    <td width="300px">Name</td>
    <td width="158px">IP Address</td>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row_inventorystaff['staff_id']; ?><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['staff_id']; ?></td>
      <td><a href="index.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_inventorystaff['staff_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $row_inventorystaff['f_name']; ?> <?php echo $row_inventorystaff['l_name']; ?></a><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['f_name']; ?> <?php echo $row_DetailRS1['l_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_inventorystaff['ip_address']; ?><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['ip_address']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_inventorystaff = mysql_fetch_assoc($inventorystaff)); ?>
</table>
<br />
<table border="0" style="margin-left:15px;" >
  <tr>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_inventorystaff > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_inventorystaff=%d%s", $currentPage, 0, $queryString_inventorystaff); ?>">First</a>
    <?php } // Show if not first page ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_inventorystaff > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_inventorystaff=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $pageNum_inventorystaff - 1), $queryString_inventorystaff); ?>">Previous</a>
    <?php } // Show if not first page ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_inventorystaff < $totalPages_inventorystaff) { // Show if not last page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_inventorystaff=%d%s", $currentPage, min($totalPages_inventorystaff, $pageNum_inventorystaff + 1), $queryString_inventorystaff); ?>">Next</a>
    <?php } // Show if not last page ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_inventorystaff < $totalPages_inventorystaff) { // Show if not last page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_inventorystaff=%d%s", $currentPage, $totalPages_inventorystaff, $queryString_inventorystaff); ?>">Last</a>
    <?php } // Show if not last page ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p style="margin_left:15px">Records <?php echo ($startRow_inventorystaff + 1) ?> to <?php echo min($startRow_inventorystaff + $maxRows_inventorystaff, $totalRows_inventorystaff) ?> of <?php echo $totalRows_inventorystaff ?>
</p>
```

I have screen shots of the process of clicking through the index and performing a search that I can upload if it helps the explanation.

Comment: Does your Staff Search form itself include `$_POST['Staff']` somewhere? Because otherwise you're not getting to the includes any more.

Comment: save the result in hidden form fields `<input type="hidden"`, so the next query will contain all previous data.

Comment: Fred-ii- include_once didn't seem to make a difference. @NiettheDarkAbsol - the staffsearch.php code has been included in the edit.

Comment: @quicksilver As I suspected, you should try adding `<input type="hidden" name="Staff" />` to your `staffsearch.php` form.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - that was both better and worse, hahaha. Adding that made the staffsearch.php and details.php includes continue to display after submitting my search but it caused two other problems. First, the navigation links (First, Previous, Next Last) stopped working (sending to the include-less blank page). Secondly, I try to conduct another search it appends the first query to the new one's results (eg. I search for "Adam" then search for "Bob" all of the "Bob's" show up with "Adam" stuck to the end of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a radio button to make a decision which will be easier to parse. Double submit buttons are a funny thing and some browsers dont like that.

```
  <input name="dept" value="staff" type="radio"> Staff
  <input name="dept" value="hardware" type="radio"> Hardware
 <?php
   if( isset($_POST['dept'] && $_POST['dept'] == 'staff' ) {
     include 'staffForm.php';
   } else {
    include 'hardwareForm.php';
   }
?>
```

Comment: Why would more than one submit button cause a problem? Define "some browsers". I doubt that very very much.

Comment: Maybe it was my gut telling me, either way - check if values are being passed over. with PHP print_r($_POST) will show all of your post values.

Comment: The print_r($_POST) is as follows: "Array ( )" when I first navigate to the page. "Array ( [Staff] => Staff )" after I click the staff button. Back to "Array ( )" when I enter a search term and click submit. Then "Array ( [Staff] => Staff )" after the search is submitted and I click staff to get the results. This back and forth continues as I click a link to get details and click staff again to make them display.

Comment: So when you clicked 'Staff', staff variable was set in the POST array, as it you'd expect. What happens when you click Hardware?